# Delete all items in a list that don't contain a regular expression string

Tags: python, regex, list, iteration

Is it possible to delete all items in a list that don't contain a regular expression string?

I was thinking of maybe returning only a regular expression string, and if there wasn't one, making the list item empty, and then iterating over the list a second time to delete all the empty entries, but that seems inefficient.

Any thoughts?

For example, lets say I have:

```
["cat", "dog", "monkey", "Fred", "sad"]
```

and I write a regex that only selects for sad. I want all of the others to be (preferably) deleted.

Comment: You need to rewrite your question to be more clear about what you want. Are you looking for a one-to-one match between regexes and strings? Or are you trying to test each string with each regex (cartesian product)?

Comment: Ok so I have a list of words. I want to go through this list, and compare it to another list of phrases, and check when ANY of the words from the first list, is in the second, and record # of occurrences per word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to construct a new list using a list comprehension:

```
regex = re.compile(...)
new_list = [s for s in old_list if regex.match(s)]
```

or, using `filter()`:

```
new_list = filter(regex.match, old_list)
```

Comment: Here's code:            wordlist = ['sad', 'mad', 'im', 'cats', 'dogs', 'goats']
            new_list = [s for s in tweets if re.match(wordlist)]
            print new_list

Comment: Getting "match() takes at least 2 arguments"

Comment: Oh wait, looked into .compile - you can't compile a list though.

Comment: You're supposed to compile a regular expression, not a list.

Comment: Fill in the (...) with your regular expression, not your list.  Then when you use the match method on the compiled regular expression object (not the match function in the re module, which is different) it should work.

Comment: I want to use a list of regular expression objects, though. Like, I want to search for one regular expression inside a list item, and then another, and another. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: That's not what you said in your question at all.